# MYSQL, where if exists

Tags: mysql, if-statement, exists

I have 3 tables. User, alert and pref. User is obviously my user info table. Alert is my table where I store user alert/notification settings and pref is where I store my user preferences.

Not all users will have entries for prefs and alerts. When I'm trying to make a call for my alerts I'm running into trouble with my SQL knowledge.

I'm trying to do a 3 way join on user, alert and pref where the uid's are the same. I want to Select all user.id and ignore all uids that have an alert.deleted and pref.deleted = 1

```
    user    |    alert    |    pref
id           uid           uid
             alert_id      pref_id
             deleted       deleted
```

Comment: That's the schema, which is great, but where's the query where you *tried* to do the join?

Comment: Did you try left outer join with deleted field in join condition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do that is

```
SELECT id
FROM   user
WHERE  user.id not in (SELECT uid FROM alert WHERE deleted = 1)
AND    user.id not in (SELECT uid FROM pref WHERE deleted = 1);
```

But if you meant to say you want all users that actually have an alert and pref, just not the ones that are deleted, you could use

```
SELECT     id
FROM       user
INNER JOIN pref
ON         user.id = pref.uid
AND        pref.deleted = 0
INNER JOIN alert
ON         user.id = alert.uid
AND        alert.deleted = 0;
```

In your question you are talking about getting the alerts, so maybe there aren't any prefs necessarily for a particular user, but you do want all the not-yet-deleted alerts, then use

```
SELECT          id
FROM            user
LEFT OUTER JOIN pref
ON              user.id = pref.uid
AND             pref.deleted = 0
INNER JOIN      alert
ON              user.id = alert.uid
AND             alert.deleted = 0;
```

Take your pick.

Comment: Please make SQL keywords CAPS, its convention.

Comment: Dont you think INNER JOIN is better way ?

Comment: @ jQuery.PHP.Magento.com - No. It could be that there are NO records for a particular user in either alert or pref. And he wants to return ALL users, except the ones that have a deleted alert or pref. That, or he didn't ask his question correctly.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT id
FROM user u
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM alert WHERE uid = u.id AND deleted = 1)
  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM pref WHERE uid = u.id AND deleted = 1)
;
```